# Java Applet slow when using ByteArrayStream

Tags: java, caching, applet, iostream

I am transforming xml in an object of an own class called "V6BasicCar", the problem that I'm having is that if I enable the Java cache (in Java control panel):

[image]

each transformation takes about 3-4 seconds, but if I disable caching, it takes just miliseconds. I don't know why this happens, my only guess is that Java is caching the ByteArrayStream  per transformation and that makes it slower, but I haven't figured out how to deal with this problem. Is there any alternative to ByteArray Stream that would be faster?

Thanks.

The code:

```
{
..

ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

//1. transform xml    
transform(getSourceXml(_intype), out);

//2. convert to bean
XsdConverter<V6BasicCar> v6BasicCarXsdConverter = new XsdConverter<V6BasicCar>(V6BasicCar.class);     
    /* 
    "getObject()" takes about 2 secs 
    */
V6BasicCar newV6BasicCar = v6BasicCarXsdConverter.getObject(convert(out));

..
}


 protected InputStream getSourceXml(final CsvWrapperMiddle _csvV6Car) throws IOException, JAXBException
{
    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();   

        /* 
        "getXml" takes about 2 secs 
        */
    xsdConverter.getXml(_csvV6Car.getExternalBean(), out); 
    InputStream output = convert(out);   
    return output;
}

protected InputStream convert(ByteArrayOutputStream out)
{
    return new ByteArrayInputStream(out.toByteArray());
}
```

Comment: The Java chache is for downloaded jar files, not for the data the ByteArray(In|Out)putStream is holding. I don't really think this should influence things here. The problem might be in the xsdConverter.

Comment: Okay it looks like the problem was inside the XsdConverter as you said, specifically in JAXB. Setting "com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.fastBoot" to true fixed the problem :) Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was inside the XsdConverter, specifically in JAXB. Setting "com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.fastBoot" to true fixed the problem